# how to fix print statement in exception handling{except block}?

Tags: python

Here the problem is in exception handling where i take a [list] and iterate that list using for loop. now inside the for loop there is try and catch block where in try block i divide 1 through the list `element(r = 1/int(entry))` but in list we have multiple datatypes such string, int, etc, etc,. Now the problem is when divisible is done successfully i want to print this print("the reciprocal of", entry ,"is",r)

```
import sys

lst = [2, 'b' ,0]

for entry in lst:
    try:
        print("the entry is ", entry)
        r = 1/int(entry)
    except:            
        print("oop!", sys.exc_info()[0],"occured")
        print("Next entry.")
        print("**************************")
        if(r == True):
            print("the reciprocal of", entry ,"is",r)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

lst = [2, 'b' ,0]

for entry in lst:
    try:
        print("the entry is ", entry)
        r = 1/int(entry)
        print("the reciprocal of", entry ,"is",r)
    except:            
        print("oop!", sys.exc_info()[0],"occured")
        print("Next entry.")
        print("**************************")
```